# What does 'They while away their evenings with books and games.' mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs, parts-of-speech

I was asked to name the highlighted part of speech in the given sentence.

> They ***while*** away the evenings with books and games.

the sentence, however didn't felt grammatically correct to me, and I didn't know what the sentence actually meant. So I said ***verb*** arbitrarily, which to my surprise was the correct answer. Can anyone explain me what the sentence actually mean and how is ***while*** a verb here?

Comment: It's [while away](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/while%20away) as a "phrasal verb" — you wouldn't use 'while' as a verb on its own.

Comment: Of interest: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40959/which-is-correct-while-away-or-wile-away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whiled away; whiling away; whiles away
**Definition of while away**
: to spend (time) doing something pleasant and easy
We whiled away the afternoon with a walk around the garden.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/while%20away)